# Configure perforce to use proxy server

Tags: proxy, perforce, assembla

As the title says, I need to configure perforce to use a proxy server. To clarify, I am not talking about using Perforce Proxy, but to actually connect to the perforce server (in this case perforce.assembla.com:1666) through a proxy.

Comment: Most commonly-used uses of "proxy server" refer to HTTP proxies, but the Perforce client-server protocol is not HTTP, so HTTP proxies are of no benefit in proxying Perforce traffic.

Comment: Did you figure out how Perforce can use a SOCKS proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a SOCKS proxy.
There are plenty of open source solutions depending on the platform you are using. https://wiki.debian.org/SOCKS

Comment: And how would you configure Perforce to use that proxy?

Answer (score 0):

The only way i've found so far to do this is by installing an extra software that forces perforce to use a socks proxy.

1) you set up whatever proxy you want to use

2) you install [AllProxy](http://very-soft.com/product/allproxy)

3) Add your proxy to the proxy list

4) In Manage Rules add a rule. 
- On Proxy choose your proxy
- On programs add perforce. Search for p4v.exe (or whatever) (its easier if perforce is already running). 
- On remote destination specify the port, or leave to any.

Then use perforce as normal.

Note: there's a default route that goes direct (not using proxy).
Also for HTTP proxy you can set it globally under Windows Proxy settings (on Win10), or use AllProxy.

Note2: This info is based on [this](https://superuser.com/a/1341297/204468) answer.

Note3: AllProxy is the only listed soft that worked for me. You could still try the [longer route](https://superuser.com/a/1342227/204468).